# AP statistics question

Tags: statistics

A bag contains 2 black and 2 white marbles, and there is a supply of extra marbles of each color. A move consists of randomly drawing 2 marbles from the bag. If the marbles are the same color, they are replaced by two black marbles. If they are different collors they are replaced by two white marbles.

Find the probability that after 4 moves, all the marbles are black in the bag. Give Answer as fraction, reduced to Lowest terms.

Please help. I’m not doing well in statistics and need to answer this problem!

Comment: Please tell us how much you know and what you have tried

Comment: There are few enough ways this experiment can play out that it should be feasible to work them all out with pencil and paper and add the relevant probabilities.

Comment: I tried using a couple combination solutions, but I'm not getting very far..

Answer (score -1):

Hint:  There are five states of the bag.  From each state you can go to a maximum of three others.  So there are (at most) 15 transition probabilities to figure-in fact a few less.  For example, from (2B,2W) the chance to go to (4B,0W) is $\frac 16$ as you have to draw the two white balls.  What is the probability distribution after one draw?  Then keep going.

Comment: Why cant you get to all white? You can easily get to all white after two moves, with a 1/4 probability.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum:  correct.  brain glitch fixed

Comment: What do you mean by a probability distribution

Comment: @user62044:  It is $\frac 16$ that it will be four black as I said.  The other choices now are three white, one black or two white, two black.  If you calculate the chance of each of those, you will have the probability distribution after one draw.  Given that, you can figure the distribution after two draws.  You take each of the possible states after one draw (one of which you have already figured out) and find the chance that each will go to the possible next states.  Multiply those chances by the chance you were in each state, add up the common ones, and yo have the distribution after two.